# I want to build a battery charger to charge my wife's 48 volt e-bike battery using the 12V socket in the RV. Is that possible?

Tags: battery-charging

I want to build a battery charger to charge my wife's 48 volt Nicad e-bike battery using the 12V socket in the RV.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  You could use or build a DC/DC boost converter to step up 12V to 55ish volts, and then an appropriate battery charger electronics for the NiCd.  Good design is essential to not ruin your pack (or with less docile chemistries, set it on fire. Many house fires happen from lithium batteries mis-charged, sometimes by amateur or uncertified charging equipment).

And even if you're where the stakes are low, you are far better off using commercial battery management IC's that know how to do 3-stage charging and you just have to add the support components mentioned on the data sheet, rather than try to wing your own charger from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is a 12VDC - 120VAC inverter and use that for a proper NiCd charger. There are many risks to a DIY battery charger, although NiCd is more forgiving than a LiPo battery. You can get a boost converter with constant current and constant voltage adjustments. If you really want to design and build one, find and post some appropriate circuits an someone might help you with specific issues.